# Setting up CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I downloaded a custom build for CKEditor open source from the website and followed the documentation to set it up. I put the following in my header.html file which is included in EVERY file:

```
<script src="./includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
        };
    </script>
```

I was under the impression that this would load the script and then replace all <textarea> fields in forms with the editor but i'm just getting basic editors as default with textarea's. Any idea? All files were uploaded to the root/includes/ckeditor directory when unzipped.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an apache permissions issue. Problem solved.